# Not able to find Azure Traffic Manager PowerShell Cmdlets

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to manage (create profile etc) Azure Traffic Manager through PowerShell Cmdlets.

I am NOT able to find any cmdlets in Azure SDK 2.2 especially in Windows Azure PowerShell. I used Get-Command and checked all cmdlets, but not able to find even a single on for Traffic Manager. Please help me find traffic manager cmdlets.

I found these resources, but not sure if they are relevant now - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/01/26/new-management-api-for-windows-azure-traffic-manager.aspx

In the above resource, there is link to codeplex site which is broken.

NOTE: I need cmdlets, I already refered REST API specs.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Traffic manager is not yet supported by the Windows Azure PowerShell. We're looking forward to doing this work in the future, however.

Comment: Jeff Wilcox, Do we have any other alternate way? probably importing some modules and using them in powershell? And exactly when do Microsoft planning to include Traffic Manager cmdlets in PowerShell?

Comment: @ramiramilu -  As you mentioned in your question, you already found the alternate way - the [Traffic Manger REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh758255.aspx). You can build your own cmdlets or scripts or code on top of these. You can look at the GitHub repo Igorek pointed you to, for both PowerShell implementations and node-based CLI implementations of other API calls, to serve as examples.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell cmdlets for Traffic Manager were shipped in the last release of May 2014.

You can find the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690250.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This github page has the latest version of Azure Powershell and their source code
https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools

Comment: Igorek, I knew about the source code. But isn't that Microsoft needs to include TM cmdlets in SDK 2.2. It is been mentioned in Windown Azure blog (the link I shared about TM cmdlets), but they are not included. Also in source code and commits, I am not able to find any Traffic manager related stuff.